# JpaRepository query "in" (Hibernate)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have a JpaRepository:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    List<User> getByFirstName(String firstName);
}
```

But how to search in several values? I need something like this:

```
List<User> getByFirstNames(List<String> firstNames);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the signature of the method to:

```
List<User> getByFirstNameIn(List<String> firstNames);
```

Take a look at all the supported method of Spring Data JPA on [their reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation).

Answer (score 0):

The following code is working,
Code in Repository,

```
List<Shop> findByNameIn(List<String> names);
```

Code in controller,

```
List<String> names=new ArrayList<String>();
names.add("gunaa");
names.add("pranav");

List<Shop> sl=shopService.findByNameIn(names);
for(Shop s:sl)
    System.out.println(s.getName());
```